# codeigniter how to pass base_url() from controller

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to pass the **base_url() from controller to view..Without echoing it in the view it self, I want to pass it in the array as below**,

```
$data= array(
'url'=> "<a href='".base_url()."/method/parm'>click</a>"
);
```

how can i do this??

Thanks!

Comment: [Click](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view).

Comment: without echo in view means you cannot pass the data from controller to view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you'll need to pass your $data variable

```
$data['sample'] = "<a href='".base_url()."/method/parm'>click</a>";
$this->load->view('myview',$data);
```

then in your view just echo the index you want

**View example**

```
<div>
<?php echo $sample; ?>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I can't deal with the view..link will automatically convert to a link but base_url() will remain the same..I want it to be echo automatically..

Answer (score 1):

Open **/application/config/config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'your base url'; // Ex:'http://localhost/testproject/'
```

Answer (score 1):

on your controller:

```
$data['base_url'] = base_url();
$this->load->view('myview',$data);
```

on your view

just type

```
<a href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/method/parm">click</a>
```